# error using riverpod to The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, riverpod

While using `fromJson`

> Method this error occurs
> The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

```
final fetchUserProvider = FutureProvider((ref) {
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1';
  return http
      .get(Uri.parse(url))
      .then((response) => UserModel.fromJson(response.body));//error 
});
```

```
class UserModel {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String username;

  const UserModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.username,
  });

  static UserModel fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserModel(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      username: json['username'],
    );
  }

  @override
  String toString() => "$id, $name, $username";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decode the response body with `jsonDecode`(From `dart:convert;`) while from JSON, except map`fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)`

```dart
return http
      .get(Uri.parse(url))
      .then((response) => UserModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body))); // i prefer `await` over `then`
```